Lenovo IdeaPad-5-2-in-1-16AHP9 Display Issue
On a new 24.04 install the Lenovo IdeaPad-5-2-in-1-16AHP9 display default was correct at 1920 x 1200 90Hz.   After upgrades to 24.04.1 or a new 24.04.1 install the display resolution is correct, but the refresh rate is set to 60Hz with no ability to change it to 90Hz.   40, 50 & 60 HZ are the only refresh rates shown in Settings.
Also, the ability to control the keyboard backlight via the space bar was lost and the backlight is always on at one intensity.  What can be done to regain this functionality?
The laptop uses the AMD Radeon M780 integrated graphics.
